# How to prevent to pass css attributes to the inner elements?

Tags: css

I'm creating 3 tables.

```
<table id="first">
    <tr>
        <td>
        1. CAPTION
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="second">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        2. CAPTION
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="" width="100" height="100" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="third">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        3. CAPTION
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="" width="100" height="100" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to add 10px padding (padding-top:10px) for the main table td elements.

```
#first tr td
{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 0pt;
}
```

But this padding is adding to inner tables td elements.

[image]

How can i prevent to pass padding-top setting to the inner tables?

Answer (score 2):

Use `#first > tr > td`.

It means "a td that is a *direct* child of a tr that is a *direct* child of an element with ID 'first'".

Comment: It's worth noting that this doesn't work in Internet Explorer 6 (just in case you have to support it).

Comment: But there is no change, when i add "border:10px solid blue;" to the "#first > tr > td" .

Comment: IE6 doesn't support E > F? Lame.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions.

One (the hard way),
Specify padding values to the inner child elements so that it over-rides the parent style specifications.

Two (the above method),
Use '#first > tr > td'
but, it leads to cross browser comparability issues.

ie-6 does have a large share of the browser market.